# TLS handshake times out for a few users only

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, apache-2.4, openssl, timeout

A few of my clients are unable to visit any of my HTTPS-enabled websites. The browser spends a lot of time negotiating the TLS handshake. Ultimately, a timeout occurs.

The server: Apache2 on Ubuntu, SSL certificate from Let's Encrypt (which I do not think matters because the handshake fails). Several name-based hosts delivering a variety of sites, including static HTML sites and PHP sites, and reverse-proxying into Docker containers with a number of web applications (based on Ruby, Go, PHP).

The clients: Windows 7, Firefox 66 or Internet Explorer 11, with and without third-party antivirus/security software.

When one of my clients let me establish a remote session on their computer, I was able to see the problem on the client side myself. I watched the Apache2 error log (with `LogLevel trace7`) at the same time, it provided no meaningful information other than an eventual `AH01998: Connection closed to child [x] with abortive shutdown`.

The websites work fine for everyone else. They are indexed in the major search engines. SSL Labs does not show any problems with SSL/TLS configuration. I have attempted to reproduce the problem with a Windows 7 virtual box with Firefox and Internet Explorer, both of which were able to load the TLS-enabled websites without problem.

Things that I have tried, all to no avail:

- Turned off "internet security" software and restarted the client's browser (in the remote session).
- Disabled any custom SSL configuration in the Apache2 server (except the certificate configuration of course).
- Verified that the client's computer has plenty of free RAM (gigabytes).
- Verified that the client's IP addresses appear nowhere in the iptables of my server.
- Verified that the clients can see non-HTTPS-enabled sites on my server.
- Invoked the Firefox developer tools in the client's browser while attempting to load the page via HTTPS -- nothing to be seen.
- Upgraded the entire Ubuntu server from 18.04 with Apache2 2.4.29 and OpenSSL 1.1.0g to Ubuntu server 19.04 with Apache2 2.4.38 and OpenSSL 1.1.1b.

There are a few reports of failing TLS handshakes on the internet, but none of them provides a solution for this particular problem.

What else could I do to find out the cause of the problem?

Comment: From your description this looks more like a client side problem, like a corporate firewall there which interferes with the SSL or some IDS which for some reason generates false alarms and throws away packets. It would be useful to do packet captures both in the client side and on the server side and compare. My expectation would be that some data send by the client don't reach the server or some data send by the server don't reach the client.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. We're not in a corporate environment, so no corporate firewall/IDS, but maybe the ISP interferes... I guess I'll have to capture the packets to find out.